# How to save a command on a npm project

Tags: npm

See, i work with angular and everytime i need to run the "ng serve", i have to run this command first
`export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`
And, i mean, is not a big problem nor everything, but if i could not do this always, it would be much better, u know?
So i wanted to know if there is somehow a way to save this command on git bash so when i type, idk, "export", autocomplete it for me. Can i do something like that?

I actually don't know how can i solve this, so i always write `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` before run the ng serve.

Answer (score 1):

write this command in your package.json as a scripts

```
{
 "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider ng serve",
    "dummyName": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider ng serve"
    "build": "ng build",
   ...
   ...
}
```

after this just run command `npm start` or `npm run dummyName` to run this script.